# Generic function to convert a CSV file to an object

Tags: vb.net, generics

I want to implement generic method to read two types of CSV files. I have created two classes to represent each of those csv files. Can any one tell me how to write a generic function ReadFile(Of T) and generate objects.

Thanks

I'm adding the function I have created for this. Please advise the correct way of achieving this.

```
 Public Function ReadFile(Of THeader, TRecord, TTrailer, TResult)(fileName As String) As IData(Of TRecord)
        Dim objHeader As IHeader = Nothing
        Dim objTrailer As ITrailer = Nothing
        Dim objRecord As TRecord = Nothing
        Dim colRecords As Collection(Of TRecord) = Nothing
        Dim objData As IData(Of TRecord) = Nothing

        Using objDataReader As OleDbDataReader = objTextReader.Read("SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "] WHERE RecordType='A'")
            If objDataReader.HasRows Then
                While objDataReader.Read
                    objHeader = Activator.CreateInstance(Of THeader)()

                    With objHeader.GetType
                        .GetProperty("ReportType").SetValue(objHeader, objDataReader(1).ToString, Nothing)
                        .GetProperty("FileDate").SetValue(objHeader, objDataReader(2).ToString, Nothing)
                        .GetProperty("FileTime").SetValue(objHeader, objDataReader(3).ToString, Nothing)
                    End With
                End While
            End If
        End Using

        Using objDataReader As OleDbDataReader = objTextReader.Read("SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "] WHERE RecordType='B'")
            colRecords = New Collection(Of TRecord)
            Dim objPropInfo() As PropertyInfo

            If objDataReader.HasRows Then
                While objDataReader.Read
                    objRecord = Activator.CreateInstance(Of TRecord)()
                    objPropInfo = objRecord.GetType.GetProperties()

                    For Each propInfo In objPropInfo
                        If propInfo.Name <> "FormattedAccountTitle" And propInfo.Name <> "FormattedParticipantName" Then
                            'propInfo.SetValue(objRecord, If(objDataReader(propInfo.Name) Is DBNull.Value, "", objDataReader(propInfo.Name)), Nothing)
                            propInfo.SetValue(objRecord, objDataReader(propInfo.Name).ToString, Nothing)
                        End If
                    Next

                    colRecords.Add(objRecord)
                End While
            End If
        End Using

        Using objDataReader As OleDbDataReader = objTextReader.Read("SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "] WHERE RecordType='Z'")
            If objDataReader.HasRows Then
                While objDataReader.Read
                    objTrailer = Activator.CreateInstance(Of TTrailer)()

                    With objTrailer.GetType
                        .GetProperty("RecordCount").SetValue(objTrailer, objDataReader(1).ToString, Nothing)
                    End With
                End While
            End If
        End Using

        objData = Activator.CreateInstance(Of TResult)()

        With objData.GetType
            .GetProperty("Header").SetValue(objData, objHeader, Nothing)
            .GetProperty("Records").SetValue(objData, colRecords, Nothing)
            .GetProperty("Trailer").SetValue(objData, objTrailer, Nothing)
        End With

        Return objData
    End Function
```

**Below is the sample CSV files:**

**CSV1:**

```
A,T18,04SEP2013,101540,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
B,012345678,2013,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
B,,,1234567890,Mr Johnathan Peter Jones,Mr,Johnathan Peter,Jones,,Y,2,1,2,"Griffin House, Silver Head Street",Sheffield,,,,12A456,ZZ,01041960,10245.45,2548.15
B,,,1234567890,Miss Jane Elizabeth Smith,Mr,Johnathan Peter,Jones,,Y,2,2,2,"Griffin House, Silver Head Street",Sheffield,,,,12A456,ZZ,01041960,10245.45,2548.15
B,,,1234567899,Mr JSimon Soanes,Mr,Simon,Soanes,,Y,1,1,1,Abc Building Xyz street,Sheffield,,,,12AB516,ZZ,01091966,88245.45,4148.15
Z,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

**CSV2:**

```
A,T17,17SEP2013,143021,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
B,1SDFDDGT,,2013,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
B,,,400109,1234FFFFFFFFFFF,Samsung Mobiles,,,,Samsung,N,1,1,1,Samsung Corporation Private Limited,"West Avenue, 4th Division, Devonshire Lane",,,United Kingdom,258DFF,ZZ,21524154,,123888.25,2562.78,Y,N
B,,,400120,1234FSDUFFFFFFF,Sony Mobiles,,,,Sony,N,1,1,1,Sony Corporation Private Limited,,,,United Kingdom,255DFF,ZZ,216666154,,123888.25,2562.78,N,N
Z,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Users of this forum are very unlikely to write code for you.  But many would be happy to offer helpful suggestions regarding code that you've written yourself.

Comment: Please show the code you already have and a sample of your CSV Input data. Also show that you have tried solving this for yourself.

Comment: Do you want to do this using ALGOL, LISP or whitespace?

Comment: Thanks @scottb, updated my post with code I'm trying to write.

Comment: @piet.t I'm trying this in VB.NET.

Comment: What's up with all those `obj` and `col` prefixes? It makes the code hard to read. Also, it seems that your code misses some type constraints: e.g. `objData` is declared as `IData(Of TRecord)`, but later an instance of `TResult` is assigned to it, but there's no relation between `TResult` and `IData(Of TRecord)`.

Comment: @DominicKexel I'm trying to write a generic function to read different CSV files. I have added TResult type as I'm unable to create an object of type IData(Of TRecord) its throwing some exception. I'm new to generics, please let me know if it can be done in a better way.

Comment: Can anyone suggest best way of doing this please.

Comment: is it not possible to do like this?